# How to find a word in a single long string?

Tags: lua

I want to be able to copy and paste a large string of words from say a text document where there are spaces, returns and not commas between each and every word. Then i want to be able to take out each word individually and put them in a table for example...

```
input:
please i need help

output:
{1, "please"},
{2, "i"},
{3, "need"},
{4, "help"}
(i will have the table already made with the second column set to like " ")
```

havent tried anything yet as nothing has come to mind and all i could think of was using gsub to turn spaces into commas and find a solution from there but again i dont think that would work out so well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delimiters are spaces ( ), commas (`,`) and newlines (`\n`, sometimes `\r\n` or `\r`, the latter very rarely). You now want to find words delimited by these delimiters. A word is a sequence of one or more non-delimiter characters. This trivially translates to a Lua pattern which can be fed into `gmatch`. Paired with a loop & inserting the matches in a table you get the following:

```lua
local words = {}
for word in input:gmatch"[^ ,\r\n]+" do
    table.insert(words, word)
end
```

if you know that your words are gonna be in your locale-specific character set (usually ASCII or extended ASCII), you can use Lua's `%w` character class for matching sequences of alphanumeric characters:

```lua
local words = {}
for word in input:gmatch"%w+" do
    table.insert(words, word)
end
```

Note: The resulting table will be in "list" form:

```lua
{
    [1] = "first",
    [2] = "second",
    [3] = "third",
}
```

(for which `{"first", "second", "third"}` would be shorthand)

I don't see any good reasons for the table format you have described, but it can be trivially created by inserting tables instead of strings into the list.

Comment: okay so i tried it like this (no other code)

    `local input = "yes no"
    local words = {}
    for word in input:gmatch"[^ ,\r\n]+" do
    table.insert(words, word)
    end`

so now how do i put the words in to a module table

Comment: "Two letters"? Two words ("yes" and "no") you mean? Printing the table can be as simple as `for _, word in ipairs(words) do print(word) end`. `print(table.concat(words, "\n))` also works.

Comment: sorry i fixed it to be asking the proper question

Comment: even so, i tried what you suggested ,
    `local input = "yes no maybe"
    local words = {}
    for word in input:gmatch"[^ ,\r\n]+" do
    table.insert(words, word)
    print(table.concat(words, "\n"))
    end`
and yet the output was
yes
yes
no
yes
no
maybe

Comment: nvm i found how to do it thanks man this helped alot